# In yii,why can't I get all parameters using yii::app()->getParams() method?

Tags: php, yii

In my program,I called getParams() method,but only got 10 parameters.In my main.php configuration file,there is more,why?
Here is the params part of the main.php

```
 'params'=>array(

    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    'AccountDB' => 'db_account_dev',
    'orderDB' => 'db_order_dev',
'staticPath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
    'commonDB' => 'db_common',
    'payDB' => 'db_pay_dev',
    'crmDB' => 'db_crm_dev',
    'queue' => array(
        'email' => array(
            array(
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 11300,
            ),
        ),
        'sms' => array(
            array(
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 11330,
            ),
        ),
        'sale_record' => array(
            array(
                 'host' => '192.168.0.201',
                 'port' => 11300,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'discuz' => array(
        'DBName'    => 'db_ultrax',
        'TablePrefix'  => 'pre_',
        'authKey'   => '00fefan5JEvKdiEQ',
    ),
    'freight' => require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'freight.php'),
    'allowCheckTaskSubId' => 224,
    'allowCheckEmail' => 242,
    'allowCheckPass' => 243,
    'codFee' => 10,
    'cancelFee' => 10,
```

)

However,the method only returns some items

1. adminEmail=>webmaster@example.com
2. orderDB=>db_order_dev
3. payDB=>db_pay
4. AccountDB=>db_account
5. commonDB=>db_common
6. freight=>Array
7. codFee=>10
8. saleRoleId=>9
9. saleManager=>11
10. growth=>Array

Comment: How do you know there should be more? How would *we* know without any real information?

Comment: Oh,I got the main.php configuration file

Comment: Well,I just got confused

Comment: Without any code it's hard to know why, but my guess is that it could be as simple as optional parameters?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the params on the same server you access them? When you look at the output, you will see that there are also differences in value, which honestly cannot happen because of Yii. Or is it a caching problem? I think you have different configs on your dev and production.

Comment: Oh,I see，the configuration file of console application should be protected/console.php ,but not the main.php

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer.
The configuration file of console application is protected/config/console.php
while the configuration file of web application is protected/config/main.php
They are different!
The above codes from a console application